# Lower Navigation Controller Back Button and Text

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, back

I have standard looking back buttons that are created with the help of `Navigation Controller` and I need to move them +5 pt down on each screen my app have.

I haven't found any info about this topic, so I'm wondering if this possible at all without making custom buttons? Or maybe I wasn't searching good.

Possible solution that comes to my mind is to manually increase height of navigation bar, but I'm looking for a better way of making this task.

Would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Any screenshot of what you're trying to do?

Comment: use `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment` to change title position.

Comment: @Rocky will this move button sign like < and text together?

Comment: @Glenn I have standard looking back buttons like here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/45fFk.png

And I need to place them a bit lower, so that they have bottom alignment to nav bar